# Problema al crear multiples objetos, las variables son iguales por alguna razon

Tags: java, array, java-8

Estoy haciendo una pequeña red neuronal que detecte la letra la cosa es que me atore en una cosa que puede parecer básica, creo un objeto neurona por cada letra, solo son esas 7, cada letra tiene 3 letras diferentes asi como en pixeles algo asi.

```
..##...

...#...

...#...

..#.#..

..#.#..

.#####.

.#...#.

.#...#.

###.###
```

Esa es una "A" y asi con todas las letras

Tengo 3 diseños para cada tipo de letra leo los patrones y los paso a una 3 arrays y luego esos arreglos los convierto a un array bipolar asi de "1" y "-1" pero cuando imprimo esos arreglos bipolares para ver si lo hice bien (imprimo el primer arreglo de "a" y el primero de "b") y me imprime lo mismo.

***Mi constructor*** es asi, más adelante pongo el método que uso para leer los archivos.

```
public elPratronizaje() throws IOException {
    a = new Neurona("C:\\Users\\CHOME\\Desktop\\Letras_entrenamiento\\A.txt");
    b = new Neurona("C:\\Users\\CHOME\\Desktop\\Letras_entrenamiento\\B.txt");
    c = new Neurona("C:\\Users\\CHOME\\Desktop\\Letras_entrenamiento\\C.txt");
    d = new Neurona("C:\\Users\\CHOME\\Desktop\\Letras_entrenamiento\\D.txt");
    e = new Neurona("C:\\Users\\CHOME\\Desktop\\Letras_entrenamiento\\E.txt");
    j = new Neurona("C:\\Users\\CHOME\\Desktop\\Letras_entrenamiento\\J.txt");
    k = new Neurona("C:\\Users\\CHOME\\Desktop\\Letras_entrenamiento\\K.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        System.out.print(a.getLetrasBipolares()[0][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(a.getLetrasBipolares()[0].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        System.out.print(b.getLetrasBipolares()[0][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(b.getLetrasBipolares()[0].length);

}
```

***Método que uso para leer los archivos***

```
void leer(String archivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
    while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
        letra += cadena;
        int aux = letra.length();
       // System.out.println(cadena);
    }
    b.close();
}
```

y esto para convertir el texto a cadenas bipolares del tipo int, que es el ***constructor de la clase neurona***

```
public Neurona(String archivo) throws IOException {
    leer(archivo);
    letras[0] = "."+letra.substring(0,63);
    letras[1] = "."+letra.substring(63,126);
    letras[2] = "."+letra.substring(126,189);
    letrasAux[0] = letras[0].toCharArray();
    letrasAux[1] = letras[1].toCharArray();
    letrasAux[2] = letras[2].toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 64 ; i++) {
        if (letrasAux[0][i] == '#'){
            letrasBipolares[0][i] = 1;
        }else if (letrasAux[0][i] == '.'){
            letrasBipolares[0][i] = -1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 64 ; i++) {
        if (letrasAux[1][i] == '#'){
            letrasBipolares[1][i] = 1;
        }else if (letrasAux[1][i] == '.'){
            letrasBipolares[1][i] = -1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 64 ; i++) {
        if (letrasAux[2][i] == '#'){
            letrasBipolares[2][i] = 1;
        }else if (letrasAux[2][i] == '.'){
            letrasBipolares[2][i] = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: De casualidad no estas declarando letra como estático?

Comment: si, de hecho si

Comment: Pues ahí tienes tu problema... letra contiene todos tus archivos en un solo String, cambialo a una variable de instancia en vez de clase. y como siempre obtienes los primeros 189 chars de la cadena, el resultado siempre será el mismo

Comment: Gracias lo voy a probar

Comment: si era eso, muchísimas gracias :D

Comment: Considerad mover el comentario de @Ajeno a una respuesta y aceptarla, siempre siguiendo [answer]